# RXSwift Binding returns Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, swift4, rx-swift

I'm a beginner to MVVM and RxSwift and I want to implement it on my next project. Currently, I'm working on my login module, everything looks fine but every time I run my application it triggers an error when binding text field to my ViewModel saying "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".

Can anybody help me to get rid of it?
Here's how I do it:

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var loginButton: UIButton!

    private var loginViewModel: UserLoginViewModel!
    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

         emailTextField.rx.text.orEmpty
            .bind(to: loginViewModel.emailAdd)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag) <---- Displays "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

         passwordTextField.rx.text.orEmpty
            .bind(to: loginViewModel.password)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag) <---- Displays "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
    }
}


/////loginProtocol

protocol loginProtocol {
    //MARK - Input
    var emailAdd: Variable<String> { get }
    var password: Variable<String> { get }
    var loginButtonDidTap:PublishSubject<Void>{ get }
    var loginActionResult: Driver<AutenticationStatus> { get }
}


/// VIEW MODEL
class UserLoginViewModel: loginProtocol {
    var emailAdd: Variable<String>
    var password: Variable<String>
    let loginButtonDidTap = PublishSubject<Void>()
    var loginActionResult:Driver<AutenticationStatus>

    init(apiService: API) {
        let emailV = Variable<String>("")
        let passwordV = Variable<String>("")
        emailAdd = emailV
        password = passwordV
        let usernameAndPassword = Observable.combineLatest(emailAdd.asObservable(), password.asObservable()) {
            ($0, $1)
        }

        loginActionResult = loginButtonDidTap.asObservable()
            .withLatestFrom(usernameAndPassword)
            .flatMapLatest { (emailAdd, password) in
                return apiService.login(email: emailAdd, password: password)
            }.asDriver(onErrorJustReturn:.error(.server))
    }
}
```

[image: Here's the screenshot]

Thank you.

Comment: The only object that is not initialized in your code above is `loginViewModel`

Answer (score 5):

In your code the outlets or the ViewModel could be nil. If your code section is complete, the `loginViewModel` will never be created.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // create view model
    loginViewModel = UserLoginViewModel(apiService: /* your api service */)

    emailTextField.rx.text.orEmpty
        .bind(to: loginViewModel.emailAdd)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)

    passwordTextField.rx.text.orEmpty
        .bind(to: loginViewModel.password)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I just found out the error. The LoginViewModel was not initialized.
I fixed the error by initializing the loginViewModel. Here's how I do it

```
 var viewModel:LoginViewModel!
     override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            self.viewModel = LoginViewModel(apiService: APIManager.sharedManager)
        }
```